# Haskell: search list

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, now I have a question here.
If I have a list `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`, and I want use a function like `searchList x = 3`, then output 4, how to dual with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3afilter) high order function:

```
search :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int
search list n = head (head (filter (\(x:xs) -> x == n) list))
```

What this `search` function does is to filter the elements of the passed list of lists, selecting only the ones which have the passed value n as head. Then takes only one (The first, thats why the first (right) `head` is used), and then extracts the first element of that list (Using `head` again).

If you want to store a list of pairs, I suggest you to use tuples instead of lists as elements of the list.

**EDIT:** As people suggested in comments, if you use tuples there is a function `lookup` on the prelude that implements this kind of searching.

Comment: If you do choose to store it as `[(Int,Int)]`, `lookup` will do. Maybe you can add that to the answer?

Comment: And if the list is empty or there is no match, you get a handy runtime error!

Answer (score 1):

So what you have a list of lists and you want to search it, find the element that matches [x,y] and return y.

```
searchList x (y:ys) = if x == head y then last y else searchList x ys
searchList x [] = -1
```

Which behaves like so:

```
Main> :load searchlist.hs 
Main> searchList 3 [ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6] ]
4
Main> searchList 5 [ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6] ]
6
Main> searchList 6 [ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6] ]
-1
```

As an aside it is uncommon to use lists in Haskell if you want a fixed width, like the pairs in your list. It would be more Haskell-ish to use a list of tuples, like so.

```
searchListTuples x (y:ys) = if x == fst y then snd y else searchListTuples x ys
searchListTuples x [] = -1
```

Which of course behaves very similarly:

```
Main> searchListTuples 3 [ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6) ]
4
Main> searchListTuples 5 [ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6) ]
6
Main> searchListTuples 6 [ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6) ]
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
searchList x y = last $ head $ dropWhile (\[a,_]->a/=x) y
```

Or, in pointfree notation:

```
searchList = ((last . head) .) . dropWhile . (. head) . (/=)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this recursive function, but a "-1" as a bad value is not a normal Haskell idiom. Use Maybe.

```
searchListTuples x (y:ys) = if x == fst y then Just (snd y) else SearchListTuples x ys
searchListTuples x [] = Nothing
```